# An inequality about pseudohyperbolic metric on $\mathbb{D}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

We know that the pseudohyperbolic metric on $\mathbb{D}$ is defined by 
$$\rho(z,w)=|\varphi_z(w)|=\left|\frac{z-w}{1-\overline{z}w}\right|$$
where $\varphi_z$ is the Mobius transform given by $\varphi_z(w)=\frac{z-w}{1-\overline{z}w}$.

My problem is to show that for any fixed $\xi\in{\mathbb{D}}$ there is a constant $C_{\xi}>0$ such that 
$$\rho(\varphi_z(\xi),\varphi_w(\xi))<C_{\xi}\rho(z,w),\forall{z,w\in{\mathbb{D}}}.$$

I know that this result is true. I couldn't prove it although I have worked on it for a long time. Thanks for your attention and help.

Answer (score 0):

Proof. First of all, we consider the case $w=0$. In this case , for all $z\in{\mathbb{D}}$ we have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\rho\left(\varphi_z(\xi),\varphi_w(\xi)\right)
&=\rho(\varphi_z(\xi),-\xi)=\left|\frac{\varphi_z(\xi)+\xi}{1+\overline{\varphi_z(\xi)}\xi}\right|\\
&=\frac{|z-\overline{z}\xi^2|}{|1-z\overline{\xi}+\overline{z}\xi-|\xi|^2|}\\
&\leq\frac{2|z|}{1-|\xi|^2}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
where the last in equality holds since $-z\overline{\xi}+\overline{z}\xi$ is pure imaginary.

In general, for any $z,w\in{\mathbb{D}}$ we have
$$\rho\left(\varphi_z(\xi),\varphi_w(\xi)\right)=\rho\left(\xi,\varphi_z\circ\varphi_w(\xi)\right).$$
Since $\varphi_{\varphi_z(w)}\circ\varphi_z\circ\varphi_w(0)=0$ and $\varphi_{\varphi_z(w)}\circ\varphi_z\circ\varphi_w\in{\text{Aut}}(\mathbb{D})$, it is just a rotation. There is a unimodular constant $\lambda$ such that 
$$\varphi_{\varphi_z(w)}\circ\varphi_z\circ\varphi_w(\zeta)=\lambda\zeta,\text{ i.e., }\varphi_z\circ\varphi_w(\zeta)=\varphi_{\varphi_z(w)}(\lambda\zeta), \text{ for all }\zeta\in{\mathbb{D}}.$$
To get $\lambda$, we take differential on both sides on the last equation and obtain
$$\varphi_z'(\varphi_w(\zeta))\varphi_w'(\zeta)=\lambda\varphi_{\varphi_z(w)}'(\lambda\zeta).$$
Taking $\zeta=0$, we get 
$$\lambda=\frac{\varphi_z'(w)\varphi_w'(0)}{\varphi_{\varphi_z(w)}'(0)}=-\frac{1-z\overline{w}}{1-\overline{z}w}.$$
Triangle inequality of pseudohyperbolic metric gives 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\rho\left(\varphi_z(\xi),\varphi_w(\xi)\right)
&=\rho\left(\xi,\varphi_z\circ\varphi_w(\xi)\right)=\rho\left(\xi,\varphi_{\varphi_z(w)}(\lambda\xi)\right)\\
&=\rho\left(\varphi_{\varphi_z(w)}(\xi),\lambda\xi\right)\\
&\leq\rho\left(\varphi_{\varphi_z(w)}(\xi),-\xi\right)+\rho\left(-\xi,\lambda\xi\right).
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
By above discussion, we have $\rho\left(\varphi_{\varphi_z(w)}(\xi),-\xi\right)\leq\frac{2|\varphi_z(w)|}{1-|\xi|^2}$. For the second term, we have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\rho\left(-\xi,\lambda\xi\right)
&=\left|\frac{\xi+\lambda\xi}{1+\lambda|\xi|^2}\right|\leq\frac{|\xi||1+\lambda|}{1-|\xi|^2}.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Moreover, we have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
|1+\lambda|
&=\left|1-\frac{1-z\overline{w}}{1-\overline{z}w}\right|=\left|\frac{z\overline{w}-\overline{z}w}{1-\overline{z}w}\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{z\overline{w}-w\overline{w}+w\overline{w}-\overline{z}w}{1-\overline{z}w}\right|\\
&\leq|w|\left|\frac{z-w}{1-\overline{z}w}\right|+|w|\left|\frac{\overline{w}-\overline{z}}{1-\overline{z}w}\right|\\
&\leq2|\varphi_z(w)|.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
In conclusion, we get 
$$\rho\left(\varphi_z(\xi),\varphi_w(\xi)\right)\leq{\frac{2+2|\xi|^2}{1-|\xi|^2}}\rho(z,w),\text{ for all }z,w\in{\mathbb{D}}.$$